# Showing images on table cell click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an iPhone app. In that I am displaying some content in a table cell. Now, I want to display the full-size image when click on the table cell.
I used the following code. But I don't know how to display the image in full screen when I select the table cell.
And also I want to get back when I tap on background when the image is in full screen.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_beaconDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT vendor_name, enter_message, enter_image, received_date, time_interval FROM beacons WHERE id=%@",  [unique objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_beaconDB,
                       query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            title = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithUTF8String:
                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                 statement, 0)];
            description = [[NSString alloc]
                            initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                            sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

            fullImg = [[NSString alloc]
                           initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                           sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

            NSString *receivedDate = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                                     sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

            NSString *timeInterval = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

            BeaconAdTime *beaconAdTime = [[BeaconAdTime alloc] init];
            NSDate *updatedTime = [beaconAdTime updatedDateTime:receivedDate andInterval:[timeInterval intValue]];

            while (updatedTime!=nil)
            {
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"MMM-dd hh:mm a"];
                BeaconAdTime *beaconAdTime = [[BeaconAdTime alloc] init];
                NSString *presentDateTime = [beaconAdTime presentDateTime];
                NSDate *presentDateConvert = [dateFormatter dateFromString:presentDateTime];

                if(updatedTime <= presentDateConvert)
                {
//                        [message insertObject:description atIndex:indexPath.row];
//                        [vendor insertObject:title atIndex:indexPath.row];
                    cell.title.text = title;
                    cell.description.text = description;
                    cell.receivedDate.text = receivedDate;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(_beaconDB);
}
cell.title.text = vendor[indexPath.row];

cell.vendorImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gg.jpg"];

//    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailImg]]];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hey you can add UIImageView Object to the same screen with full size of the device and make it as Hidden innitially .. Then Add - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; delegate method of tableview and set that image selected image to UIImageview object and Make  it hidden FALSE. ..... Once you will see the image coverd by whole screen you can make it hidden again by tap gesture recogniser method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = tableView.visibleCells[indexPath.row];
    UIViewController *imageVC = [UIViewController new];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    imageVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageVC.view.frame];
    imageView.image = cell.imageView.image;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouched:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
    [self presentViewController:imageVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

let me know if you need explanation and/or further help

Comment: add `imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`

Comment: 1.on the UITableViewController you are overriding this method. 2.you are creating an view controller with a UIImageView -  both has the size of the screen. 3.you add a tap gesture. 4.you present it. If you want the photo to cover only part of the photo just change the frame of the UIImageView. In the method of the tapGestureRecognier - "imageTouched" you can check if the touch is inside the photo or on the background.

Comment: target-
An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value.
action-
A selector that identifies the method implemented by the target to handle the gesture recognized by the receiver. The action selector must conform to the signature described in the class overview. NULL is not a valid value.

Comment: If you put the cursor on the method signature you can see the description of the variables on the left side of the screen. 
Is it working for you? can you confirm the answer (by checking the v) ?

Comment: Here i am using Custom cell for table view. Will the above code work or i have to change something

Comment: You need to change the UITableViewCell to the custom one and the imageView to yours. imageView is a "built in" variable in UITableViewCell

Comment: can u update the above answer with code. Beacuse I dont know where i have to give the image name

Comment: sorry.. the cell.imageView.image to: cell.yourImageViewVariableName.image

Comment: its working but when i click on the image its remains on same its not going back

Comment: did you implement imageTouched? you need to implement it and call     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
or something similar - depends on the project's structure - navigation/tabs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a drill-down table interface.

Here's an example from Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app. Also, here's the official reference from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html.

Good luck!